# 'if' scenario in an equation. How do I implement it?

Tags: numerical

Basically I've been trying to make a working hours calculator and I've run into a problem. When the start time's value is greater than the finish time (eg. start is 23 and finish is 19), the result comes up as a negative. So what I want it to do in that scenario is to then multiply the negative  number by -1 to make it positive again. However, this code below doesn't seem to have any effect in my app.

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    int result = [finishHours.text intValue] - [startHours.text intValue];
    totalHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", result];
    if (result < 0) {
            result = result * -1;

    }
```

Comment: And what if you want to calculate a time for a night shift?

Comment: No need to multiply: result = -result, or just replace the whole if with result = abs(result).

Comment: @Vladimir: How would I go about doing that? I'm sorry, I'm very new at this.

Comment: you can add 24hours instead of multiple by -1 in case of negative time.

Comment: so I move the totalHours.text line above the int result line?

Answer (score 4):

You set totalHours.text **before** you change the sign of your result variable.

Comment: Thank you, Vladmir. You've helped me tons!

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean it doesn't have any effect?  is it because you have changed result after you have set totalHours?  would this fix your issue?

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {
int result = [finishHours.text intValue] - [startHours.text intValue];
if (result < 0) {
        result = result * -1;

}
totalHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", result];
```